# Avatar cycle that matches the zodiac

Tags: avatars, astrology, rashi

Has there ever been an avatar cycle that matches the zodiac?

This doesn’t quite make sense except with animals crab, Scorpio, Aquarius, etc.  it makes sense mostly.

Another way to phrase my question do avatars have birthdays that match a specific month?

Comment: What is an avatar cycle?

Comment: @Wikash_ Vishnu Avatars .. I think he is asking if Vishnu Avatars, or Something similar to God Incarnations(Avatar) That comes to earth, consecutively, matching their zodiac symbol with birth month_or_something..etc.. 12Avatar Cycle that Matches 12Zodiac Cycle..

Comment: So he means by cycle a Mahayuga?